# How to get a remote file and set it as a value for a file field using entity metadata wrappers?

Tags: 7, files, entities

I am trying to get a remote pdf file from a web service and save it as a field's value using `entity_metadata_wrapper`, but somehow I couldn't get it working.

I can successfully retrieve the file using `system_retrieve_file` and save it locally. However, I couldn't set the file field's value to this newly retrieved file.

Here is my code (simplified):

```
// Retrieve the file from the web service.
// This works, I can see and open the retrieved file.
$file = system_retrieve_file($file_url, 'public://path/', TRUE);
$file = (array) $file;
var_dump($file);

$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid)

// Set this file as a value for the node's file field.
// I've tried following lines individually and they both failed.
$ewrapper->field_pdffile->set($file);
$ewrapper->field_pdffile->set(array($file));
```

Both methods I've tried raised the following error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set() (line 122 of /drupal/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

I'm setting in the same code block other fields as well and they are set and saved without any error if I skip the file field.

For example, the following lines are working in the same code block for other fields:

```
// I'm getting the text from the web service
$ewrapper->field_text->set($some_text);
// I'm getting a term from web service
// Creating it if it doesn't already exist, and saving the 'term id' like:
$ewrapper->field_term->set($tid);
// A few more various fields are successfully set like that...
// Except that file field, which returns the above exception:
$ewrapper->field_pdffile->set($file);
```

What could it be, that I'm doing wrong?

### UPDATE:

I've added a `var_dump($file)` and I'm getting the following output, which seems alright to me:

```
array(17) {
  'fid' => string(5) "13037"
  'uid' => string(1) "1"
  'filename' => string(31) "sample.pdf"
  'uri' => string(54) "public://path/sample.pdf"
  'filemime' => string(15) "application/pdf"
  'filesize' => string(6) "129804"
  'status' => string(1) "1"
  'timestamp' => string(10) "1409924961"
  'type' => string(8) "document"
  'uuid' => string(36) "a06f6bf7-61e1-48fd-bfc7-8bff6e72705f"
  'metadata' => array(0) {}
  'alt' => string(0) ""
  'title' => string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: Why not to use [FileField Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) or "borrow" it's code? ;)

Comment: @Mołot I didn't know about this module, but it wouldn't help me much since I'm not only saving this field, I am actually importing the whole node from a webservice. I can successfully save all other fields except this file field using entity_metadata_wrappers.

Comment: Well, I have no experience with this kind of job, I just know this module works in the part you seem to have problem with, and it is open source, so maybe you could use the fact it is open source? Not an answer, just a rough idea.

Comment: If it would used entity_metadata_wrapper to save the field, I could get some help from their code, but it doesn't. As you would already know, there are many ways to save fields programmatically, but the recommended way is using entity_metadata_wrapper. Since I'm using this method for all other fields and it works, I would be happy to save this file field as well using EMW, so that I don't have to rewrite the whole module using field arrays, which is, let's admit, ugly, such as: $field_name['und'][0]['fid']. And inconsistent for all fields.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Did you try to display the output of `$file` variable (with var_dump or devel)? Are you sure you're getting the file object with `system_retrieve_file()`? this error can be seen If you set the field as required and if it gets null value, or wrong type (you can see it in `validate` method in `entity.wrapper.inc`). Check [this](http://codepad.org/fKfrTZ71), `set` method is working fine with typecasted object (stdclass)..

Comment: @xurshid29 Thanks for your response, I'd already checked the output of `$file` using `var_dump`. I've updated my question and added the output, which seems alright to me.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Hey, I tested filefield with pdf file, `set` mrthod works perfectly, here is a [link](http://codepad.org/thuFxhBl), may be problem is n your field settings(admin ui)?

Comment: @xurshid29 Thanks! I'll check the field and instance settings.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. I think I found the solution to your problem:) Modify that array before setting, add `description`, `display`, `origname`(same as `filename`) keys, unset `type`, `metadata`, `uuid`, then put it to `set` method.

Comment: Thanks @xurshid29, I think I've found the problem. I've skipped  this time another field and it now seems to be working. I'll debug it around and write it here. If that's the reason, I should close this question since then it is off-topic. Thank you anyway for your efforts!

Comment: @xurshid29 Many thanks! That was the issue. I've added `$file['display'] = 1; $file['description'] = '';` and it's working now :) You should post this as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @xurshid29 never post [the correct answer](http://codepad.org/thuFxhBl) here, I am posting it cause I find it "hard" to retrieve the comments:

(from @ЕлинЙ post)

```
// Retrieve file from web service (this works, I can see and open the retrieved file)
$file = system_retrieve_file($file_url, 'public://path/', TRUE);
$file = (array) $file;
$file['display'] = 1;
$file['description'] = '';

$ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid)

// Set this file as a value for the node's file field.
$ewrapper->field_pdffile->set($file);
```

*More info on [system_retrieve_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7.x)*

And thanks to both of you for your work!